# Program for school is not working

Tags: python

I'm a python noob and for school I need to write a program that has 6 options:

1. Find Square root
2. Average test scores
3. Show tax
4. Randomness
5. find the amount of days of a date and today
6. and exit

I have all this complete except the date. Here is my code:

```
   #test.py
    from math import *
    from random import *
    from datetime import *
    cont = True
    a = 0
    print("My Custom Functions")
    print("1. What's the root?")
    print("2. Average my test scores.")
    print("3. Show me the tax.")
    print("4. Randomness.")
    print("5. How many days?")
    print("6. Exit")

    def option():
     cont = True
     global a
     global cont
     o = input("Enter an option")
     if o == "1":
        a = float(input("This function prints a square root. Enter a number (1-9999):"))
        print(sqrt(a))
    if o == "2":
        b = input("Enter any number of test scores (1-100). Separate each by a space:")
        l = []
    l = [float(score) for score in b.split()]
    avg =sum(l) / len(l)
    print(round(avg,5))
    if o == "3":
        c = float(input("This function shows how much your sales tax (7.5%) is for your purchase. Enter the purchase amount (<10,000):"))
        d = c * .075
        print("$",c+d)
    if o == "4":
     print(randrange(1,100))
    if o == "5":
        d = input("“This function shows how many days there are between today and a date you enter. Enter a date in this format (mm dd yy):")
        int(d)
        d1 = date(d)
        d2 = date.today()
        print(d2 - d1)
    if o == "6":
        print("Exitting Program")
        cont = False

    while cont == True:
    option()
```

I have edited the code as the answers I have received advised. I now get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 24 18'. I have researched for a solution, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

For option 2, convert to float *after* splitting the string.

```
b = input("Enter any number of test scores (1-100). Separate each by a space:")
l = [float(score) for score in b.split()]
print(sum(l) / len(l))
```

---

For option 5, you need to use the `datetime.date` objects properly.

```
d = input("“This function shows how many days there are between today and a date you enter. Enter a date in this format (mm dd yy):")
mm, dd, yy = [int(t) for t in d.split()]
d1 = date(2000 + yy, mm, dd)
print((date.today() - d1).days)
```

Comment: if user not typing "Hello !"

Comment: I fixed 2, I'm still having trouble with 5.

Comment: @Mike:  added details for 5.

Answer (score 0):

A list of space separated `float`s is not a `float`, you need to first split it, and *then* convert them to floats:

```
if o == "2":
    b = input("Enter any number of test scores (1-100). Separate each by a space:")
    l = list(map(float, b.split()))  # or use a list comprehension
    print(sum(l) / len(l))
```

And you can't convert a date to an `int`, that doesn't makes sense.